# Flutter listview inside overlay

Tags: flutter, macos

I am creating an macOS like overlay menu with a list of options you can choose from. I want to have the overlay to have a max height. I have implemented the widget and it looks like how I want, but the problem is that the list inside the overlay does not scroll.

Does anyone know how to add a list view inside an overlay?

This is my code so far

```
class OverLayButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Widget Function(
      BuildContext context, OverlayPortalController controller) overlayBuilder;

  const OverLayButton({
    super.key,
    required this.overlayBuilder,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  State<OverLayButton> createState() => _OverLayButtonState();
}

class _OverLayButtonState extends State<OverLayButton> {
  late final OverlayPortalController _controller;
  final _link = LayerLink();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = OverlayPortalController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: _link,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          padding: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(EdgeInsets.all(0)),
          overlayColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
          foregroundColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
          surfaceTintColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
          shadowColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
          backgroundColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
          iconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
            return Colors.white;
          }),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          _controller.toggle();
        },
        child: OverlayPortal(
          controller: _controller,
          overlayChildBuilder: (context) {
            return CompositedTransformFollower(
              link: _link,
              targetAnchor: Alignment.topLeft,
              followerAnchor: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Align(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromRGBO(30, 30, 30, 1),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: CupertinoColors.systemGrey3.darkColor,
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                        offset: const Offset(0, 5),
                        spreadRadius: 1.0,
                        blurRadius: 10.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                        sigmaX: 20.0,
                        sigmaY: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: widget.overlayBuilder(context, _controller),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: widget.child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
                  OverLayButton(
                    overlayBuilder: (context, controller) {
                      return Container(
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                          minHeight: 28,
                          maxHeight: 600,
                          maxWidth: 400,
                        ),
                        child: ListView(
                          primary: false,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text("hello"),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text("hello"),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text("hello"),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text("hello"),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text("hello"),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text("hello"),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text("hello"),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.mic,
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: list inside the overlay does not scroll. because the size of maxHeight: 600 is higher than the height of the 7 ListTiles, put more ListTiles or change the maxHeight, for example, to maxHeight:100 and you will see the scroll.

Comment: @FranklinDiaz thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this is not the case. Even when I have 30 ListTiles the list won't scroll. But the list does scroll when controlled by the scrollbar.

Comment: I think that it has something to do with focus?

Comment: oh I have tried the code on idx.google.com and the scroll works for me, I don't know if I understand the problem correctly. Just to try, try this:
key: const PageStorageKey("list"),
controller: ScrollController(),